# Processes accessing a Shared Memory segment returning different values

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory, ipcs

I'm new to the IPCS concept,i want to achieve that one process creates and initializes a shared memory and then calls another process which attaches to the same shared memory segment and prints the data in the shared memory.
However i'm unable to achieve it:

AlgoCommon.h

```
struct sub_algo_shm
{
int time;
int pno;
};
struct AlgoShm
{
int head;
int tail;
char fFlag;
struct sub_algo_shm algoshm;
};
```

AlgoThrottle.c

```
#define key (key_t)111119
#define SHM_SIZE 1024

    int main()
        {
                int shmid ;
                struct timeval CurTime;
                struct timespec nTime;
                struct AlgoShm *shmaddr,*ptr;

                ptr = (struct AlgoShm *)malloc(10*sizeof(struct AlgoShm));
                //Creating Shared Memory
                if((shmid = shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,0644 |IPC_CREAT)) < 0)
                {
                        perror("shmget:error");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("Shm created key=[%d] \n Segment Id [%d] ",key,shmid);
                        //Attaching to Shared Memory
                        shmaddr = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
                        if(shmaddr < 0)
                        {
                                perror(" shmat :error");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                printf(" SHM Segment attached at [%x] ",shmaddr);
                        }
                        //Loading/Initializing Data Blocks in SHM
                        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&nTime);
                        printf(" Time in N secs[%ld] \n ",nTime.tv_nsec);
                        ptr->head = 5;
                        ptr->tail = 3;
                        ptr->fFlag = '0';
                        ptr->algoshm.time = 0;
                        ptr->algoshm.pno = 1;
                        //memcpy(shmaddr,&ptr,sizeof(ptr));
                        printf(" AlgoThrottle|ptr->head [%d] ",ptr->head);
                //      sleep(1);
                        system("./AlgoRead"); 

                }

        return 0;
        }
```

AlgoRead.c

```
#define key (key_t)111119
#define SHM_SIZE 1024

    int main()
    {

    int shmid ;
    struct AlgoShm *shmaddr,*ptr1 ;
    ptr1 = (struct AlgoShm *)malloc(10*sizeof(struct AlgoShm));

    if((shmid = shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,0)) < 0)
    {

    perror(" AlgoRead|shmget:error ");
    }
    else
    {
            printf(" AlgoRead|SHM Created shmid [%d] ",shmid);

            if((shmaddr = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0)) < 0)
            {
                    perror("AlgoRead|shmat error");
            }
            else
            {
                    //memcpy(ptr1,shmaddr,sizeof(struct AlgoShm));
                    printf(" AlgoRead|Attached to Segment at Address[%x] \n ",shmaddr);
                    printf(" AlgoRead|ptr1->head [%d] ptr1->tail [%d] ptr1->fFlag[%c] \n ",ptr1->head,ptr1->tail,ptr1->fFlag);
            }
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

This is my output:

```
Shm created key=[111119]
 Segment Id [1179615678]  SHM Segment attached at [4a6b4000]  Time in N secs[114594083]
 AlgoRead|SHM Created shmid [1179615678]  AlgoRead|Attached to Segment at Address[624cb000]
  AlgoRead|ptr1->head [36810768] ptr1->tail [0] ptr1->fFlag[▒]
   AlgoThrottle|ptr->head [5]
```

Also,system call's output is showing first then the printf statement even after i used a sleep(1) before invoking system()

Comment: What is `key`?  Where is it defined?  Please post **complete** code.

Comment: edited with key,defined at same place

Comment: where you define the structure "AlgoShm" ? Does head, tail & fFlag are members of this structure ?

Comment: they are defined in a header file which is included in both processes,edited the code.

Comment: when i commented those 'memcpy' in both processes,i get 0 for both head and tail for the second process,seems it's displaying the default value for the structure and not the one in the shared memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing, if you are using `shared memory` then why `malloc()` ? shared memory itself will attach `shmid` with `shared memory` you don't have to do  explicitly malloc().

second thing, you are attaching `shmaddr` pointer with memory returned by `shmat()` but **putting data** into `ptr`, **ptr** is attached with **heap memory** not with **shared memory**. So either put the data into `shmaddr` pointer or replace this

```
shmaddr = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
```

with

```
ptr = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
```

and don't allocate memory using mallocc().then do

```
                ptr->head = 5;
                ptr->tail = 3;
                ptr->fFlag = '0';
                ptr->algoshm.time = 0;
                ptr->algoshm.pno = 1;
```

do all these modification in both process. and finally you should do `shmdt()` for de-attaching shared memory otherwise it will be a `memory leakage`.

I modified your code as
**one.c** :

```
int main()
{
        int shmid ;
        struct timeval CurTime;
        struct timespec nTime;
        struct AlgoShm *shmaddr,*ptr;
        if((shmid = shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,0644 |IPC_CREAT)) < 0)
        {
                perror("shmget:error");
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Shm created key=[%d] \n Segment Id [%d] ",key,shmid);
                ptr = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
                if(shmaddr < 0)
                {
                        perror(" shmat :error");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf(" SHM Segment attached at [%x] ",ptr);
                }
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&nTime);
                printf(" Time in N secs[%ld] \n ",nTime.tv_nsec);
                ptr->head = 5;
                ptr->tail = 3;
                ptr->fFlag = 'a';
                ptr->algoshm.time = 10;
                ptr->algoshm.pno = 11;
                printf(" AlgoThrottle|ptr->head [%x] ",ptr->head);

        }
        system("./AlgoRead");
        return 0;
}
```

**two.c** :

```
int main()
{
        int shmid ;
        struct AlgoShm *shmaddr,*ptr1 ;
        if((shmid = shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,0)) < 0)
        {

                perror(" AlgoRead|shmget:error ");
        }
        else
        {
                printf(" AlgoRead|SHM Created shmid [%d] ",shmid);

                if((ptr1 = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0)) < 0)
                {
                        perror("AlgoRead|shmat error");
                }
                else
                        printf(" AlgoRead|Attached to Segment at Address[%x] \n ",ptr1);
                printf(" AlgoRead|ptr1->head [%d] ptr1->tail [%d] ptr1->fFlag[%c] \n ",ptr1->head,ptr1->tail,ptr1->fFlag);
        }
        shmdt(ptr1);
        return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps you and my advise to you is to go through man page of shmget(), shmat() & shmdt() properly.

Answer (score 1):

Please see your mistakes below
why are you allocating 10 times of the structure?

correct line

```
 ptr = (struct AlgoShm *)malloc(10*sizeof(struct AlgoShm));
```

to:-

```
ptr = (struct AlgoShm *)malloc(sizeof(struct AlgoShm));
```

Do the above changes at both the c files

Now in `memcpy` why are you providing the address of a pointer `ptr` like `&ptr`? Just remove the `&`. This is not a object hence you just need to provide the pointer `ptr`. Correct it like below

```
memcpy(shmaddr,ptr,sizeof(ptr));
```

Instead of `memcpy` better use like below.

```
shmaddr->head = ptr->head;
shmaddr->tail = ptr->tail;
shmaddr->fFlag=ptr->fFlag;
```

I have re-write you code below. Try with that. Better correct your own code as per my advice.

> AlgoThrottle.c

```
int main()
{
    int shmid ;
    struct timeval CurTime;
    struct timespec nTime;
    struct AlgoShm *shmaddr,*ptr;

    ptr = (struct AlgoShm *)malloc(sizeof(struct AlgoShm));
    //Creating Shared Memory
    if((shmid = shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,0644 |IPC_CREAT)) < 0)
    {
        perror("shmget:error");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Shm created key=[%d] \n Segment Id [%d] ",key,shmid);
        //Attaching to Shared Memory
        shmaddr = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0);
        if(shmaddr < 0)
        {
                perror(" shmat :error");
        }
        else
        {
                printf(" SHM Segment attached at [%x] ",shmaddr);
        }
        //Loading/Initializing Data Blocks in SHM
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&nTime);
        printf(" Time in N secs[%ld] \n ",nTime.tv_nsec);
        ptr->head = 5;
        ptr->tail = 3;
        ptr->fFlag = '0';
        ptr->algoshm.time = 0;
        ptr->algoshm.pno = 1;
        //memcpy(shmaddr,ptr,sizeof(ptr));
        shmaddr->head = ptr->head;
        shmaddr->tail = ptr->tail;
        shmaddr->fFlag=ptr->fFlag;
        printf(" AlgoThrottle|ptr->head [%d] \n",ptr->head);
        //sleep(1);
        system("./AlgoRead"); 

    }

    return 0;
}
```

> AlgoRead.c

int main()
    {

```
    int shmid ;
    struct AlgoShm *shmaddr,*ptr1 ;
    ptr1 = (struct AlgoShm *)malloc(sizeof(struct AlgoShm));

    if((shmid = shmget(key,SHM_SIZE,0)) < 0)
    {

    perror(" AlgoRead|shmget:error ");
    }
    else
    {
            printf(" AlgoRead|SHM Created shmid [%d] ",shmid);

            if((shmaddr = (struct AlgoShm *)shmat(shmid,0,0)) < 0)
            {
                    perror("AlgoRead|shmat error");
            }
            else
            {
                    memcpy(ptr1,shmaddr,sizeof(struct AlgoShm));
                    printf(" AlgoRead|Attached to Segment at Address[%x] \n ",shmaddr);
                    printf(" AlgoRead|ptr1->head [%d] ptr1->tail [%d] ptr1->fFlag[%c] \n ",ptr1->head,ptr1->tail,ptr1->fFlag);
            }
    }

return 0;
}
```